# Why is InfluxDB queries spanning an year taking forever (> 15 minutes) to respond?

Tags: python-3.x, influxdb

I am using influxDB to save a measurement with the following schema:

```
 {
        "timestamp": self.timestamp,
        "precision": "s",
        "name": "twitter.entity.count",
        "tags": {
            "entity": ent,
            "entity_type": ent_type
        },
        "fields": {
            "count": num
        }
    }
```

And my query is

`SELECT * FROM "twitter.entity.count" WHERE entity = 'someEntity' time > '2013-01-01' AND time < '2013-12-31'`

When I tried to look at the schema in CLI, it shows the `entity` as a field and not a tag. Why is that ? Why is it auto converting my tags into fields ? How do i convert it back to tag ?

I thought the query was slow because fields are not indexed. So I tried the following query with just time field, and it is still extremely slow(> 10 mins)

`SELECT *  FROM "twitter.entity.count" WHERE  time > '2013-01-01' AND time < '2013-12-31'`

How to fix this ? I need to reduce the response time significantly (max 1s)

The machine in which I run these queries are quite huge. (24 cores, 148GB RAM)

Comment: Is there a link/analysis describing the expected query performance as a function of the time period being queried for as above.

Comment: How much data do you have to display? Did you really want to select everything except the new years eve (you selected everything before and after that single day)? If you want to fetch tens of thousands of records, then it's not really strange it's slow. Also, take a look at this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/influxdb/a0-11i7Nyas/YfQKnjNsBQAJ

Comment: First of all we must clarify that our time series granularity is in the order of a day. So in the above query, we are just selecting 365 points (one for each day of the year). We dont expect this to take such a long time

Comment: First of all we must clarify that our time series granularity is in the order of a day. So in the above query, we are just selecting 365 points (one for each day of the year). We also have only 27355 series in the database and yet retrieving 365 points takes more than an  influx -database 'demo' -execute 'SHOW SERIES' | wc -l
27355

Answer (score 0):

The reason was due to malformed entity names. The entity name had '\\' in it and it was not able be added as tags. So it was added as fields and resulted in slow query time.

Comment: The JSON write protocol is deprecated in favor of the line protocol, which is much more syntactically rigid and has fewer issues like this.